# Launch an EXE from inside a PowerShell module

Tags: powershell

This, when run from the PowerShell console, launches Internet Explorer, just as expected:

```
$ie_command = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
&$ie_command
```

If I put the same exact code inside a function within a module, it does nothing. And, yes, other code within the same function works properly, so it's not an issue of the module not being imported or anything.

Am I missing something? Why wouldn't this work?

Comment: Are you sure about this. If I put your script in a function named `ie` and put that in a module file `ie.psm1`. I can import ie.psm1, execute `ie` and up pops an IE window. Is it possible that when you execute IE a new tab is opening in an existing IE window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PS C:\SchedTasks\test> cat test.ps1
$ie_command = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
&$ie_command
PS C:\SchedTasks\test> .\test.ps1
PS C:\SchedTasks\test>
```

This brings up a browser window for me.  Are you doing anything different than this?

In any case, another way to start Internet Explorer is by using a COM adapter:

```
$ie = new-object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $True
```